# String Manipulation

Tags: apex, string

From a String of `<Meaning>Equal</Meaning>`, how can I extract only the word Equal to another string?I tried using methods subStringBefore() and subStringAfter(), but is there any other way? The string is part of bigger string with similar tags.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your goal is here. Given a string `'OneEqualTwo'`, do you want to get "Equal" as a result if the string contains the word "Equal", or remove "Equal" from the string so you're left with `'OneTwo'`? Or am I not understanding your question and you're looking for something completely different?

Comment: Edited my question. Missed to add backtick , so the tags were not appearing in my question earlier.

Comment: I want to get what comes in between the tags <Meaning> and </Meaning>
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Regular expression (RegEx) is the best functionality to use, but it does take some effort to learn.  I like [this tutorial](https://regexone.com/).

Comment: My question would be: is this potentially part of a larger XML document or document fragment? If so, have you considered using [XML loading/parsing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm)?

Comment: It is part of a large string that has many tags, but the tag<Meaning> would only appear once.

Comment: My opinion is you should probably parse the XML, especially if you need to extract other values from it now or in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following apex code can be used to extract 'Equal' enclosed between  and  tags :

```
String inputText = '<Meaning>Equal</Meaning>';
String patternString = '<Meaning>(.*?)</Meaning>';
String result = '';

System.Pattern patternTxt = System.Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcherTxt = patternTxt.matcher(inputText);

if (matcherTxt.find()) {
result = matcherTxt.group(1);
}

System.debug(result); // This will output 'Equal'
```

Comment: Thanks @Tanya Corporation. That worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want to ask is "how can I extract a string that I don't know from the middle of a string where I know its borders". Is this right? If so, then you can use `removeStart` and `removeEnd` to remove the `<Meaning>` and `</Meaning>`, respectively. This is assuming you know the contents of the borders in your string, but don't know what the content you want to get (the "Equal" string).

```
String s = '<b>text</b>';
String result = s.removeStart('<b>').removeEnd('</b>');
```

If you want to do this in a case-insensitive way, you can optionally replace those two with their counterparts `removeStartIgnoreCase` and `removeEndIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I know the tags are there, but I wouldn't know what comes in between for each request. This is part of a much bigger string with different tags.

Comment: If you are parsing an XML text, then you can do a lot with the DOM from Apex: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm